# Cassandra not replicating between two servers

Tags: nosql, cassandra

Are there any online tutorials on how to setup two basic servers up and running and replicating data.

1. I have some data in one server, and I have connected another, created the keyspace on the second server, but nothing is happening, what am I missing.
2. How do you ensure other people can't connect to port 7000. Can you use ssl certificates?

Comment: There's a tutorial here: http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/GettingStarted. This is better for 1.1 though. Which version are you using? Do the nodes list each other in `nodetool ring` (or `nodetool status` in 1.2)?

Comment: Something's broken if you had to create the keyspace manually.  They probably aren't part of the same cluster.